# ServiceMix / JPA Integration - LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean to type EntityManagerFactory

Tags: spring, jpa, apache-camel, apache-servicemix

I'm fairly new to ServiceMix / JPA / Camel / Spring.  I'm attempting to use the camel-jpa component as part of my camel route.  I'm using the latest release of ServiceMix, which is 4.5.1.  This uses camel 2.10.4 and spring 3.0.7.

After updating the OSGi manifest and deploying some additional modules to servicemix, I am stuck on the following stack trace:

```
org.osgi.service.blueprint.container.ComponentDefinitionException: Error setting property: PropertyDescriptor <name: entityManagerFactory, getter: class org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaTransactionManager.getEntityManagerFactory(, setter: [class org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaTransactionManager.setEntityManagerFactory(interface javax.persistence.EntityManagerFactory]
[...]
Caused by: java.lang.Exception: Unable to convert value org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean@46e9e26a to type javax.persistence.EntityManagerFactory
at org.apache.aries.blueprint.container.AggregateConverter.convert(AggregateConverter.java:172)[10:org.apache.aries.blueprint:0.3.2]
at org.apache.aries.blueprint.container.BlueprintRepository.convert(BlueprintRepository.java:373)[10:org.apache.aries.blueprint:0.3.2]
at org.apache.aries.blueprint.utils.ReflectionUtils$PropertyDescriptor.convert(ReflectionUtils.java:322)[10:org.apache.aries.blueprint:0.3.2]
at org.apache.aries.blueprint.utils.ReflectionUtils$MethodPropertyDescriptor.internalSet(ReflectionUtils.java:555)[10:org.apache.aries.blueprint:0.3.2]
at org.apache.aries.blueprint.utils.ReflectionUtils$PropertyDescriptor.set(ReflectionUtils.java:306)[10:org.apache.aries.blueprint:0.3.2]
at org.apache.aries.blueprint.container.BeanRecipe.setProperty(BeanRecipe.java:819)[10:org.apache.aries.blueprint:0.3.2]
```

I've played around with my persistence.xml, camel-context.xml (blueprint/spring xml) and have not been able to make much progress.  My current configuration is:

camel-context.xml

```
<bean id="mysqlDataSource" class="org.apache.commons.dbcp.BasicDataSource">
    <property name="driverClassName"        value="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver"/>
    <property name="url"                    value="jdbc:mysql://localhost/prototype"/>
    <property name="username"               value="...."/>
    <property name="password"               value="...."/>
</bean>

<bean id="entityManagerFactory" class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean">
    <property name="dataSource"             ref="mysqlDataSource"/>
    <property name="persistenceUnitName"    value="customer1"/>
    <property name="loadTimeWeaver">
        <bean class="org.springframework.instrument.classloading.SimpleLoadTimeWeaver" />
    </property>
    <property name="jpaVendorAdapter">
        <bean class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.OpenJpaVendorAdapter">
            <property name="databasePlatform"   value="org.apache.openjpa.jdbc.sql.MySQLDictionary" />
            <property name="showSql"            value="true"/>
        </bean>
    </property>
</bean>

<bean id="jpaTxManager" class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaTransactionManager">
    <property name="entityManagerFactory"   ref="entityManagerFactory"/>
</bean>

<bean id="jpa" class="org.apache.camel.component.jpa.JpaComponent">
    <property name="entityManagerFactory"   ref="entityManagerFactory"/>
    <property name="transactionManager"     ref="jpaTxManager"/>
</bean>
```

persistence.xml

```
<persistence xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence/persistence_2_0.xsd"
         version="2.0">
<persistence-unit name="customer1" transaction-type="RESOURCE_LOCAL">
    <provider>org.apache.openjpa.persistence.PersistenceProviderImpl</provider>
    <class>....</class>
</persistence-unit>
```

Any help would be appreciated.  I've been spinning on this problem for a couple days now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As your already using Blueprint using the Aries JPA and JTA features is what you need. 
For this you need to install those features also (JPA/JTA) and make sure your transaction is of type JTA, with that and using the entity manager of Aries instead of spring you should be on the safe side. A DAO will look more like the following:

```
<bean id="daoBean" class="dummy.class.name.DaoBean">
   <jpa:context property="em" unitname="customer1" />
   <tx:transaction method="*" value="Required" />
</bean>
```

For this to work properly you need to reference the corresponding blueprint schemas.

Comment: This along with some additional resources helped me to understand how to use the Blueprint / Aries JPA features.  I am past this error, but am now stuck on IllegalArgumentException.  I've created a separate thread at:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17597941/servicemix-blueprint-jpa-integration