# ServiceMix / Blueprint / JPA Integration

Tags: jpa, apache-camel, osgi, apache-servicemix, blueprint-osgi

I have been spending the week attempting to integrate JPA / ServiceMix 4.5.1 / camel-jpa 2.10.4 / Blueprint together.  I'm currently using OpenJPA, but am not tied to it.  The version of aries jpa used by servicemix is 0.3.0.

The stack trace I cannot get past is:

```
org.osgi.service.blueprint.container.ComponentDefinitionException: Error when instanciating bean workoutEntity of class class [...].WorkoutEntity
at org.apache.aries.blueprint.container.BeanRecipe.getInstance(BeanRecipe.java:271)[10:org.apache.aries.blueprint:0.3.2]
at org.apache.aries.blueprint.container.BeanRecipe.internalCreate(BeanRecipe.java:708)[10:org.apache.aries.blueprint:0.3.2]
at org.apache.aries.blueprint.di.AbstractRecipe.create(AbstractRecipe.java:64)[10:org.apache.aries.blueprint:0.3.2]
at org.apache.aries.blueprint.di.RefRecipe.internalCreate(RefRecipe.java:60)[10:org.apache.aries.blueprint:0.3.2]
at org.apache.aries.blueprint.di.AbstractRecipe.create(AbstractRecipe.java:64)[10:org.apache.aries.blueprint:0.3.2]
at org.apache.aries.blueprint.container.BlueprintRepository.createInstances(BlueprintRepository.java:219)[10:org.apache.aries.blueprint:0.3.2]
[...]
Caused by: <openjpa-2.2.0-r422266:1244990 nonfatal general error> org.apache.openjpa.persistence.PersistenceException: [javax.sql.DataSource]
at org.apache.openjpa.kernel.AbstractBrokerFactory.newBroker(AbstractBrokerFactory.java:218)
at org.apache.openjpa.kernel.DelegatingBrokerFactory.newBroker(DelegatingBrokerFactory.java:156)
at org.apache.openjpa.persistence.EntityManagerFactoryImpl.createEntityManager(EntityManagerFactoryImpl.java:227)

[...]
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: [javax.sql.DataSource]
at org.apache.aries.jndi.services.ServiceHelper.proxyPriviledged(ServiceHelper.java:348)
at org.apache.aries.jndi.services.ServiceHelper.access$700(ServiceHelper.java:65)
at org.apache.aries.jndi.services.ServiceHelper$1.run(ServiceHelper.java:285)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)[:1.6.0_43]
[...]
```

I've attempted several variations.  Here is my current configuration:

persistence.xml:

```
<persistence-unit name="customer1" transaction-type="JTA">
     <provider>org.apache.openjpa.persistence.PersistenceProviderImpl</provider>
     <jta-data-source>osgi:service/javax.sql.DataSource/(osgi.jndi.service.name=jdbc/prototypedb)</jta-data-source>
     <class>...</class>
</persistence-unit>
```

camel-context.xml

```
<service id="PrototypeDB" interface="javax.sql.DataSource">
    <service-properties>
        <entry key="osgi.jndi.service.name" value="jdbc/prototypedb"/>
    </service-properties>
    <bean class="org.apache.commons.dbcp.BasicDataSource">
        <property name="driverClassName"        value="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver"/>
        <property name="url"                    value="jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/prototype"/>
        <property name="username"               value="root"/>
        <property name="password"               value="..."/>
    </bean>
</service>

<service ref="workoutEntity" interface="..."/>
<bean id="workoutEntity" class="...">
    <jpa:unit index="0"         unitname="customer1" />
    <tx:transaction method="*"  value="Required"/>
</bean>
```

Entity Bean (written in groovy)

```
@Entity
@Table(name='customer1')
@Slf4j
class WorkoutEntity implements IWorkoutEntity{

    private EntityManager entityManager

    WorkoutEntity(final EntityManagerFactory entityManagerFactory) {
        this.entityManager = entityManagerFactory.createEntityManager()
    }

    @Handler
    void create( @Body final String input) {
         // ...
    }
}
```

I've attempted multiple different implementations of a DataSource, including the BasicDataSource, org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.SimpleDriverDataSource, and com.mysql.jdbc.jdbc2.optional.MysqlDataSource.  All cause the IllegalArgumentException.

I've also attempted to forego using JNDI and instead define the data source directly in the persistence.xml.  This causes ClassNotFoundException in the OpenJPA bundle, as it is not importing the mysql driver.  I'd prefer to define this in my camel-context.xml and would prefer to not re-bundle the OpenJPA jar.

Answer (score 2):

You probably also need the aries JNDI features installed. This helps to call OSGi services via JNDI lookups. This should be the missing piece.